# how to fix non-responding wp admin?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, optimization

I'm doing the final touches on my website and experimetning with caching and optimazation options. yesterday i tried JS minifiction, combining, and server caching. now, most options on my wp admin are not showing or not responding. when i open DEV tools on admin page, i get 22-64 errors on average. the most common issue with multiple warnings is:
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
can anyone help?
this screen shot is an example from my Divi builder plug-in settings, normaly there should be toggles next to each option. also, all plug-in options are shown in single long page instead of being orginized in diffrent pages (e.g, optimization plug-in options are shown in single page, instead of seperated into: 1- caching 2- image optimization, etc)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE1dY.png)

i tried purging all cache, even emptying all cache, clearing browser and tab cache, tried edge instead of chrome, flushed cdn cache, restored wp version, nothing worked.

Comment: Can you explain which caching plugin are you using ? Seems it is not fully compatible with other plugins and theme...